# Error while exciting the eval.py on TF object detection API

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

i'm trying to evaluate my model
using this command:

```
python eval.py --logtostderr --pipeline_config_path=training/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config --checkpoint_dir=inference_graph --eval_dir=eval
```

and im getting this error

and I'm getting this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "eval.py", line 142, in  tf.app.run() File "C:\Users\mosta\Anaconda3\envs\mat\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\platform\app.py", line 40, in run _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef) File "C:\Users\mosta\Anaconda3\envs\mat\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 299, in run _run_main(main, args) File "C:\Users\mosta\Anaconda3\envs\mat\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 250, in _run_main sys.exit(main(argv)) File "C:\Users\mosta\Anaconda3\envs\mat\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\util\deprecation.py", line 324, in new_func return func(*args, **kwargs) File "eval.py", line 138, in main graph_hook_fn=graph_rewriter_fn) File "C:\Users\mosta\Anaconda3\envs\mat\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.5.egg\object_detection\legacy\evaluator.py", line 274, in evaluate evaluator_list = get_evaluators(eval_config, categories) File "C:\Users\mosta\Anaconda3\envs\mat\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.5.egg\object_detection\legacy\evaluator.py", line 166, in get_evaluators EVAL_METRICS_CLASS_DICTeval_metric_fn_key) File "C:\Users\mosta\Anaconda3\envs\mat\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.5.egg\object_detection\utils\object_detection_evaluation.py", line 470, in **init** use_weighted_mean_ap=False) File "C:\Users\mosta\Anaconda3\envs\mat\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.5.egg\object_detection\utils\object_detection_evaluation.py", line 194, in **init** self._build_metric_names() File "C:\Users\mosta\Anaconda3\envs\mat\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.5.egg\object_detection\utils\object_detection_evaluation.py", line 213, in _build_metric_names category_name = unicode(category_name, 'utf-8') NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hi there!**

---

Python 3 renamed the **`unicode`** type to **`str`**, the old **`str`** type has been replaced by **`bytes`**.

Knowing this it makes sense that we're getting errors as parts of the TF Object Detection API are deprecated (written using Python 2.x)

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877306/nameerror-global-name-unicode-is-not-defined-in-python-3) for more explanation on how to upgrade the code to be compatible with Python 3.

---

**I hope this helps!**