# NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined while generating jmeter report

Tags: jmeter, robotframework

I am trying to generate HTML report post script execution using below robot keyword but getting  below error,

NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined

Keyword:

```
 Run Jmeter Analyse Jtl Convert To Html    ${jmeter}    ${jmxPath}  ${logPath}  -JudvData=${excelData} -Jport=${port} -Jurl=${url} -JSMS.group=1
```

If i convert jtl to html using below command via terminal it is working fine

```
sh jmeter.sh -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.*=false -g /home/sadha/Documents/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/Output/jmeterjtllog.jtl -f -o /home/sadha/Documents/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/Output/html
```

Below is the traceback log,

```
DEBUG   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sadha/PycharmProjects/NotificationService/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/JMeterClasses.py", line 107, in runJmeterAnalyseJtlConvertToHtml
    lai = LogAnalysisInitiator(logFilePath, createHtmlReport=True, disableReports=disableReports)
  File "/home/sadha/PycharmProjects/NotificationService/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/JMeterClasses.py", line 258, in __init__
    self.convertLogToHtml(disableReports)
  File "/home/sadha/PycharmProjects/NotificationService/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/JMeterClasses.py", line 299, in convertLogToHtml
    self.lc = LogConverterHtml(self, disableReports=disableReports)
  File "/home/sadha/PycharmProjects/NotificationService/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/JMeterClasses.py", line 1206, in __init__
    self.customizeNaviBar(disableReports)
  File "/home/sadha/PycharmProjects/NotificationService/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/JMeterClasses.py", line 1890, in customizeNaviBar
    if isinstance(reportOptions, unicode):
```

I am executing the script using Robot Framework so I don't see any logs in jmeter.log file

Comment: Just a thought, you have 4 days for your bounty, you can re edit with a different question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing 'unicode' with 'str' in jmeterclasses.py has resolved the issue.For more details please refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19877309/6853384

Comment: It's the first link when searching for the error message, right? I'd vote to close this question as duplicate therefore.