# xslt template to transform xml file to xml

Tags: python, xml, xslt, unicode, utf-8

Im using the python code to parse multiple .xml files

```
import os
import lxml.etree as ET
import sys

inputpath = 
xsltfile = 
outpath = 

dir = []

if sys.version_info[0] >= 3:
    unicode = str

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(inputpath):
    structure = os.path.join(outpath, dirpath[len(inputpath):])
    if not os.path.isdir(structure):
        os.mkdir(structure)
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith(('.xml')):
            dir = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
            print(dir)
            dom = ET.parse(dir)
            xslt = ET.parse(xsltfile)
            transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
            newdom = transform(dom)
            infile = unicode((ET.tostring(newdom, pretty_print=True,xml_declaration=True,standalone='yes')))
            outfile = open(structure + "\\" + filename, 'a')
            outfile.write(infile)
```

I do have an .xslt template which is used to sort the uuids in the same file.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" standalone="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="uuids">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="uuid">
            <xsl:sort select="."/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Desired Output** should be same as source unicode char's but with sortig uuid's in the same file. I see that uuids are sorting fine, but this unicode is changing to numbers which i dont want to. I

Comment: Do you have XML prolog declaration with **encoding** in the input XML?

Comment: XSLT - 
While asking a question you need to provide a **minimal reproducible example**: 
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tried to implement it.
(3) Desired output.
(4) XSLT processor and its version.

Comment: I think you should add a `python` tag your question, since the problem is not with your XSLT code, but with the way the output of the XSL transformation is serialized by your calling application.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

While asking a question it is a good idea to provide a minimal reproducible example, i.e. XML/XSLT pair.

Please try the following conceptual example.

I am using SAXON 9.7.0.15

It is very possible that the last Python line is causing the issue:

```
outfile.write(ET.tostring(newdom,pretty_print=True,xml_declaration=True,standalone='yes').decode())
```

Please try Python last lines as follows:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] >= 3:
    unicode = str
...
newdom = transform(dom)
infile = unicode((ET.tostring(newdom, pretty_print=True)))
outfile = open(structure + "\\" + filename, 'a')
outfile.write(infile, encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True, pretty_print=True)
```

https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._ElementTree-class.html#write

Reference link: [How to transform an XML file using XSLT in Python](https://izziswift.com/how-to-transform-an-xml-file-using-xslt-in-python/)

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<a:ruleInputTestConfigs xmlns:a="URI">
    <a:value xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:type="xsd:string">あいうえお@domain.com</a:value>
    <a:nameRef>email</a:nameRef>
    <a:id>1</a:id>
</a:ruleInputTestConfigs>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" standalone="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<a:ruleInputTestConfigs xmlns:a="URI">
    <a:value xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xsd:string"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">あいうえお@domain.com</a:value>
    <a:nameRef>email</a:nameRef>
    <a:id>1</a:id>
</a:ruleInputTestConfigs>
```

Comment: I tried changing it to UTF-16, but I still see that its changing the unicode to the digits.

Comment: @sandy, did yo see my comment about  a **minimal reproducible example**?

Comment: @sandy, I updated my answer too. Check it out. You still didn't provide a minimal reproducible example: ##1-4.

Comment: its an large xml file and i couldnt paste it here. and for 4. its already in .xslt template ```xsl:stylesheet version="1.0```

Comment: @sandy. We don't need the entire XML file. But we do need its prolog and a root element. There are reasons why it is called a MINIMAL reproducible example.

Comment: @sandy, I updated the answer with the Python code suggestions. Please give it a shot.

Comment: I just updated the .xml file in the question and I also tried the python change you recommended. Its throwing this error ```NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined```

Comment: @sandy, it is all explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877306/nameerror-global-name-unicode-is-not-defined-in-python-3 I updated the Python snippet.

Comment: @sandy, Are you getting the `<a:value xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xsd:string" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">あいうえお@domain.com</a:value>` correctly?

Comment: I tried adding unicode using str. But I still see the output with the number.

Comment: This is the output im getting. ```<a:value xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xsd:string"><!&#12354;&#12356;&#12358;&#12360;&#12362;@domain.com></a:value>```

Comment: @sandy. I am running out of ideas. As I see it, the XSLT is working correctly. The issue is clearly on the Python side.

Comment: Check it out here: https://lxml.de/3.6/FAQ.html "...
What is the difference between str(xslt(doc)) and xslt(doc).write() ?

"...If you call str(), it will return the serialized result as specified by the XSL transform. This correctly serializes string results to encoded Python strings and honours xsl:output options like indent. This almost certainly does what you want, so you should only use write() if you are sure that the XSLT result is an XML tree and you want to override the encoding and indentation options requested by the stylesheet.
..."

Comment: I have added the encoding=UTF-8 to the  in ```tostring(..., encoding="utf-8)```, second in ```open(..., encoding="utf-8)```. Now its giving the output as required

Comment: @sandy, good to hear good news. Please close the case.

Comment: Thanks, can you also look into this issue if you have sometime? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67677415/xslt-template-to-sort-uuids-in-xml-with-cdata-elements