# how to make python __FILE__ display symbolic path when accessed use symbol path

Tags: python, django

the __FILE__ is a convenient macro designed to access current FILE path in python. But there's some issue with it when I use it. I have a file say /home/a/b.py so when accessed from directory a the __FILE__ macro in b.py should give `/home/a/b.py` which is correct. But I then created a symbol link under /var/www/a -> /hom/a  so when the  b.py is accessed from /var/www/a I would expect macro in b.py to give the path `/var/www/a/b.py`. But this is not the case. although the file is accessed form symbol path /var/www/a, the macro is still giving the real file path `/home/a/b.py`

I've tried **abspath** and **realpath** in python os package. is there any api that can peel out the symbolic path I wanted?

Comment: Try hard links maybe? Otherwise you could set an environment variable with the configured path.

Comment: related: [How do I get the path of the current executed file in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2632199/4279)

Comment: `__file__` is not a macro (note: lowercase). It is an ordinary variable that is typically set by a module loader. Symlinks are not the only gotchas, see the link above.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian , I am a bit confused, so this is not possible? the b.py is loaded from module /var/www/a , so it should print `/var/www/a`

Comment: @zinking: [follow the link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2632199/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian can you put it as an answer, so that I can accept ?

Comment: @zinking: if you think you know the answer; you could [provide your own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the first argument from the command line if the script is called with the full path. Here's an example I just ran:

```
import sys
print(sys.argv)
```

From the command line:

```
python test.py
# results in ['test.py']
python /full/path/test.py
# results in ['/full/path/test.py']
```