# Getting current script path: __path__[0] or os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

Tags: python

What is the best practice to get the path of the currently executed script?

```
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

or

```
path = __path__[0]
```

When tried, they both output the same result.
But is one more rigorous than the other?
Is one more cross platform?

The doc says:

> This variable can be modified; doing so affects future searches for
>   modules and subpackages contained in the package. While this feature
>   is not often needed, it can be used to extend the set of modules found
>   in a package.

Apart from me modifying it explicitly, can it be modified by the interpreter without me knowing?
If so, would that return a wrong path, or is the first element always pointing to the current directory of the script?

I need that to access a config file which would be stored inside a folder called config/ in my package.
But `open("config/config.txt", 'rt')` does not work, it returns a `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Thanks.

Comment: Only [packages have a `__path__`](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#__path__), and it can be empty. Only Python 3.4 now guarantees that values in `__path__` are set to absolute paths.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the path of the current executed file in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632199/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-the-current-executed-file-in-python)

Comment: You can use `realpath` i.o. `abspath` if you want to resolve symlinks etc.