# NameError when using py2exe

Tags: python, py2exe

I'm coding a program which uses `os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))` to locate its config file and it works like a charm when I use it in pure Python, but as soon as I compile it to .exe using py2exe I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File (main.py, line 17, in <module>
NameError: name '__file__' is not defined
```

Exactly, line 17 is:

```
if os.path.isfile("%s/config.cfg" % os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))):
```

Why this happens and how I can overcome this problem?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Here is probably the solution to your problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632199/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-the-current-executed-file-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `__file__` is set by the interpreter when you're running a file as input, but not when you run your py2exe'ed executable.  You typically want to do something like this:

```
if hasattr(sys, 'frozen'):
  # retrieve path from sys.executable
  rootdir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.executable))
else:
  # assign a value from __file__
  rootdir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Comment: That fixed thing. I understand it now, thanks for explanation! :) I'll mark ur answer as correct in 4 minutes (stackoverflow isn't allowing me to do it before)... Thanks again!