# Running .exe using VBA

Tags: python, excel, exe, vba

So I created an .exe file (tlsolver.exe) to run using VBA (TLSolver.xlsm). When I launch the .exe, it runs some calculations, spits out a csv file, and then I use VBA to copy that data onto my excel sheet.

This is the VBA code I am using:

```
Public Sub StartExeWithArgument()
    Dim strProgramName As String

    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    strProgramName = "C:\Users\My.Name\Desktop\Python\Tagless\tlsolver.exe"

    Call Shell("""" & strProgramName & """", vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

When I run the macro, the console window pops up as it should and then quickly closes. I managed to see this error before it closes:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'TLSolver.xlsm'
```

I know that the .exe works perfectly fine when I doubleclick on the file regularly, so I am inclined to think that I am messing up something silly in the VBA.

Any help appreciated!

Edit: I know the sub is labeled as StartExeWithArgument, but there is no argument required, simply click and run.

Comment: Quick question... Why are you getting the error message `No such file or directory: 'TLSolver.xlsm'` why `.xlsm`? Shouldn't it be `.exe`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65643/discussion-between-ploo-and-siddharth-rout).

Comment: Post chat discussion: The exe is launching correctly from VBA. The exe was created using python and is unable to read from the .xlsm file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shell command is executing correctly. The `exe` launches and then looks for the `.xlsm` file in the current path. What is happening is that it is not able to find the `TLSolver.xlsm` in the **current directory** and hence the error `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'TLSolver.xlsm'`

Three suggestions in such a case.

1. Change the directory in VBA using `ChDir` to the directory where the excel file resides and then launch the exe **OR**
2. Place both files in the same directory. **OR**
3. Rewrite the python exe code (***This falls out of my expertise so can't help you here***) to prompt the user to select the excel file.

**VBA PART (Suggestion 1)**

```
Public Sub StartExeWithArgument()
    Dim strProgramName As String
    Dim xlFilePath As String

    '~~> Path of the excel file. Change as applicable
    xlFilePath = "C:\Temp"

    ActiveWorkbook.Save

    '~~> Change directory
    ChDir xlFilePath

    strProgramName = "C:\Users\My.Name\Desktop\Python\Tagless\tlsolver.exe"

    Call Shell("""" & strProgramName & """", vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome :) My apologies for taking so long. I actually misread the error message in the beginning.

Comment: happen to have the same problem, I modified the VBA code like this, but still it doesn't work... any idea why? if I run the .exe directly, then it can read the xlsm file...

Comment: @ilovecp3: Does the path to exe have spaces in them?

Comment: Yes, it has!! That's the problem?

Comment: @ilovecp3: Yup. You need to pad them with double quotes :)

Comment: Got it. BTW, if the exe file is in the same directory as the xlsm file, is there a way to call exe file without setting any path? Thanks.

Comment: @ilovecp3: Yes. How are you creating the Exe? Vb.Net/C#/VB6/C++?

Comment: I used python and py2exe.

Comment: @ilovecp3: Damn... This is where I back off :D If you do google search you will find the syntax for activedirectory path? Or maybe [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632199/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-the-current-executed-file-in-python) may help? Not sure :P

Comment: Thanks very much for the comments. Problem solved. I will try to avoid spaces in the path in the future.