# How do I create a string containing the filepath of my python program?

Tags: python, python-2.7

We are creating a python program that executes specific macros within Polyworks based on user input into the program. Right now the code is:

```
roto.command.CommandExecute('MACRO EXEC("C:\\RotoWorks\\Macros\\CentrifugalCompressor")')
```

However this assumes that our program is always installed in C:\RotoWorks. Ideally, our app is portable. I'm sure theres a way to retrieve the filepath that Rotoworks is stored in, then just concatenate the rest of the filepath to the end. How do I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly determine current script directory in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718657/how-to-properly-determine-current-script-directory-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the path from the `__file__` attribute of the file. Use `os.path.abspath` on that attribute to retrieve the absolute path of the file and then `os.path.dirname` to retrieve the containing directory:

```
import os

file_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
path = os.path.join(file_directory, other_path) # join directory to an inner path
roto.command.CommandExecute('MACRO EXEC({})'.format(path))
```

Use `os.path.dirname` recursively to move out as many directories as you want.

Comment: I used and it worked when running as a python script. But when I packaged it into an executable using py2exe, it says '__file__ is not defined'. How do I avoid this?

Comment: @RBuntu That would require a slightly different approach. This: [How do I get the path of the current executed file in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632199/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-the-current-executed-file-in-python)

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out