# Can't access a file in another directory using python object

Tags: python, utf-8

I wanted to implement a classification application using python 2 and before classification done text should be preprocessed. Classifier and Preprocessor are in different packages. Then I created a object of `preprocessing class` in class in classification package.

here is my project explorer

[image]

```
preprocessing class
```

> class preprocessing:
>
> ```
> def preprocess(self, file):
>
>
>     inputFile = "text"
>     outputFile = "plainText.txt"
>
>     # infile = io.open(inputFile, "r", encoding='utf-8').read()
>     outfile = io.open(outputFile, "w", encoding='utf-8')
>
>     text = unnecessaryCharsObj.removeChars(file)
>     text = stopWrdsObj.removeStopwords(text)
>
>     text = text.lower()
>     plain = text.split()
>     stemmObj.stemminig(plain)
>
>     for x in plain:
>         outfile.write(x)
>         outfile.write(u'\u0020')
>     # plaintext = " ".join(str(x) for x in plain)
>
>     # outfile.write(plaintext)
>     return outfile
>     outfile.close()
> ```

preprocessing class object that created in classidier package,

> ```
> def classify(self):
>
>     dao = DAO();
>     procc = preprocessing();
>     # Get IDs of uncatergerized news to uncatNewsList
>     uncatNewsList = dao.selectUncategerizedNews();
>
>     for news in uncatNewsList:
>
>         description = dao.getDescriptionById(news[0])
>
>         wf = io.open('news.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
>         x = description[0][0]
>         wf.write(x)
>         rf = io.open('news.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8').read()
>
>         txt = procc.preprocess(rf)
>
>         category = MultinomialNBClassifier().classifier(txt)
>         dao.updateNews(news[0],category[0])
> ```

But in preprocessing class, it uses a text file in same preprocess package. So I can't do the job as I wished since it return error `"No such file or directory: 'stopWordList.txt'"`

what can I do for solving this?

Answer (score 0):

Please check that the file is in the same path as path of the current executed file.
Here is idea:
[How do I get the path of the current executed file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632199/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-the-current-executed-file-in-python)