# How to get the path of initialization or script files in SWI-Prolog

Tags: prolog, filepath, swi-prolog

If I run the prolog scripts like this

```
user:/home/user$ swipl -f some/path/init.pl  -s another/dir/script.pl
```

How can I get the relative or full paths: `some/path` and `another/dir` or `/home/user/some/path` and `/home/user/another/dir`?
I need it to locate other files that are let's say in `another/dir/xml`.

[`working_directory/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=working_directory/2) does'nt do the job.
Neither [`source_file/1`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=source_file/1) does.

For example, for perl there is [FindBin](http://perldoc.perl.org/FindBin.html) module; also for [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632199/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-the-current-executed-file-in-python) there are options.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the directory of a source file on loading it by using [`prolog_load_context(directory, D)`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=prolog_load_context/2). For example, to switch to the directory of the loaded file, you can use:

```
:- prolog_load_context(directory, D), working_directory(_, D).
```