# I can't get the filename being executed by Python 3.6m

Tags: python, python-3.x, exec, introspection

I have tried to follow the instructions on [this node:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632199/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-the-current-executed-file-in-python)
However, if the file is using the `exec` command, all I get is this:

```
/project/cntrl_des_scripts/lior/temp/<string>

<string>

/project/cntrl_des_scripts/lior/temp/<string>
```

The main script code ran is:

```
#!/bin/python3.6m
exec( open( "foo/bar.py" ).read() )
```

The code in `foo/bar.py` is:

```
import inspect
from inspect import getsourcefile
from os.path import abspath
print( abspath(getsourcefile(lambda:0)) + "\n" )
print( inspect.getframeinfo(inspect.currentframe()).filename + "\n" )
print( abspath(getsourcefile(lambda:_)) + "\n" )
```

What I would expect the output to be is:

```
/project/cntrl_des_scripts/lior/temp/foo/bar.py
```

Comment: *why* do you expect `/project/cntrl_des_scripts/lior/temp/foo/bar.py`?

Comment: Because that is the name of the file which contains the lines being executed.

Comment: You are dynamically executing a string. Why do you think that string has any knowledge of what file you used to load it into memory?

Comment: I can get this functionality to work in Ruby... I was hoping for a similar functionality in Python.

Comment: Can you show me what you mean?