# Is there a way to get the working directory of a current python script if it is in One Drive?

Tags: python-3.x, onedrive, os.path, working-directory

My existing python script is in the One Drive and I want to get its path. I have tried all the solutions but none of them worked.

This code did not work at all.

```
import os
sys.getcwd()
```

It brought C"\users\hkay. My python file is in the one drive. The closest solution was this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632199/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-the-current-executed-file-in-python).

```
from inspect import getsourcefile
from os.path import abspath

abspath(getsourcefile(lambda:0))
```

This solution seems to bring the downloaded version of OneDrive in the temporary folder as shown below but the file is actually in OneDrive in C:\Users\hkay\OneDrive\Desktop\Project A\

'D:\TEMP\hkay\Temp\ipykernel_179044\1451747622.py'

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this question on stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271464/what-does-the-file-variable-mean-do).
It explains what `__file__` means in python.
To sum it up, it returns the path where the script was called and in combination with the `os` module, I think you can get the script directory even from One Drive.
Hope I helped you.

Comment: Sorry for delay. I will do some research on this and see what I find.